# Using Content search web part to retrieve items from another site collection

Tags: 2013, development, web-part, content-search-web-part, cross-site-publishing

I have a web application that contains two site collections(team site + enterprise wiki), with the following URLs:-

```
-http://applicationname/teamsite

-http://applicationname/enterprisewiki
```

Now I need to display the latest 10 wiki pages from the enterprise wiki site collection(according to the modified date) inside the team site. So I read that using Content search web part allow for cross-site content query.

Currently I added a new content search web part , inside my team site, and I click on “change query” button. But I am not sure how I can reference the enterprise wiki site collection's wiki page library and to specify that I need to get the latest 10 wiki pages , inside the following dialog:-

[image]

**Edit**

- I tried the following for the "Restrict by app" i chose  "Do not restrict by app".
- then i switch to advance mode , but i can not find a way to specify the site collection URL :-

[image]

**EDIT 2**

Basically this partially worked for me, I provide the following settings inside the “Build Your Query” dialog:-

- From the “Select a Query” I defined the following:- “items matching content type(system).”
- Restrict by app : “Do not restrict results by app”
- Restrict by content type “Enterprise Wiki Page”.

[image]

This showed all the sites, lists and even pages are based on the “Enterprise Wiki Page” content type.

But I am facing these problem:-

- The above setting showed only the sites,lists and pages matching the “Enterprise Wiki Page” content type, that exists on another web application, and not that exists inside the current web application.
- To test the web part , I got the following results, But I was not able to add additional info for the items  such as created by, modified by ,etc.
  [image]
- Also there is no way to sort the wiki pages by the modified date, as in the Sorting tab inside the “Build Your query” dialog I cannot find the “modified” inside the Soft by list

Answer (score 1):

The options are right in front of you.
"Restrict by App" - At the moment you have it set to 'Current Site' which is actually 'Current Web'. You would need to remove this restriction to access the full index.

Switch to Advanced Mode, ensure we are looking at Local SharePoint Results source and remove the query in the box.

Add the following:

```
Path:http://applicationname/enterprisewiki*
```

This will scope to all items under that site path.
You will need to add a filter to this to include only either 'Pages' or the 'Enterprise Wiki' content type. (or whatever content type was used for the Pages you have mentioned.)

An example of the full query as follows:

```
Path:http://applicationname/enterprisewiki* ContentType:"Enterprise Wiki Page"
```

Comment: can you check my edit please?

Comment: Copy the query in the above post and paste into 'Query Text' you can leave the existing query in there as well. This just filters all results into items only. Replace the path with the path to your site.

Comment: can you check my "EDIT 2" , as it is partilly working for me..